# How to extract SQL stored in a table as text and use it to insert the answer of that query into another table via teradata stored procedure

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table in which one of the columns has SQL query stored as text. I want to extract that query and use it in the insert statement of another table so that I can insert answer of that query into another table (SQL query returns in one row but multiple columns). HOW CAN THIS BE ACHIEVED VIA TERADATA STORED PROCEDURE?

Comment: Use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, but be aware of possible *SQL Injection*

Comment: @dnoeth thanks for the reply , but execute immediate will execute my sql text but i am not able to iterate through the cursor and use a insert statementy to insert the output of the subquery

Comment: I am using a cursor to get all the sql quries in a variable say qrytxt and then using another cursor to run the query and store the output in the variables and then using those variables in a insert statement but it is not working

Comment: You can directly run the `Insert into taget table` from a `FOR`-cursor.

Comment: Everyone is dancing around the fact that we are not looking at any SQL.  Please post.